# Android: ANT build fails with google-play-services-lib: "resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project"

Tags: java, android, linux, ant

I'm trying to build my apps using ANT and I'm failing miserably after I included the google-play-services-lib library project.

**Step 1**

I set up a reference to the library project in my project.properties file:

```
android.library.reference.1=/path/to/google-play-services_lib
```

**Step 2**

I ran these commands inside the google-play-services_lib folder:

```
android update lib-project --path .
ant clean
ant release
```

BUILD SUCCESS!

**Step 3**

Back to my project folder

```
ant clean
ant release
```

**ERROR**

```
BUILD FAILED
/android/tools/ant/build.xml:460: /path/to/google-play-services_lib resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /my/project-folder
```

There IS a project.properties in both folders, naturally. The one in google-play-services_lib contains this code:

```
target=android-8
android.library=true
```

I'm obviously missing something that's right there in front of me and I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to auto-gen the ant build.xml file until I stumbled across your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try changing the android library reference to a relative path (relative to the current directory) instead of an absolute path.

e.g.

```
android.library.reference.1=../../../relative_path/to/google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: just a note that this needs to be done in `ant.properties` which is generated after android update project -p . --target android-18

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when developing a cordova project. I copied the google-play-services-lib project folder to the same directory as the project directory and set the reference as

```
android.library.reference.2=google-play-services_lib
```

In my case I had reference to the cordova project as well, hence **android.library.reference.2**