# Add latest google_play_services_lib for ant build

Tags: java, android, ant, google-play-services, gameclosure

My android project is using ant build, And I cant upgrade to gradle build since im using gameclosure, a 3rd party game development tool.

Now I need to upgrade my google play services library.
I found that the required modules are:

**play-services-base**

**play-services-basement**

**play-services-plus**

**play-services-play**

from **$SDK-PATH/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms**

So I created individual android lib projects from above modules and added all as library project of main project.

Issue is that, play-services-base libs project whose package name is "com.google.android.gms.base", some of the class is referencing R.class file from package "com.google.android.gms". But correct value is present inside package "com.google.android.gms.base".

How to change to project settings/configs so that this R.class is generated in proper package???

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the instructions in this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265111/android-ant-build-fails-with-google-play-services-lib-resolve-to-a-path-with). It suggested to try changing the android library reference to a relative path (relative to the current directory) instead of an absolute path. You may also check on this [blog](http://www.keysolutions.com/blogs/kenyee.nsf/d6plinks/KKYE-99Y54E).

> The Play library has to be included in your project.properties file like `android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib` 
>   because it has resources that need to be included.  However, Ant will fail your build because Google no longer provides a `build.xml` for the Play library.  You can generate the `build.xml` in the Play library by running `android update lib-project --path <playlib_path>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, But where can i get latest google-play-services-lib?? now they have been split up into multiple lib projects. among which my required modules are listed in the question. @abielita